# formatting the output using printf in bash script

Tags: bash, printf

I am writing a script to display a menu at the center of the screen for the users to select the options using printf command in bash script.

I am finding the middle column of the screen, and start printing the messages from the middle column. Hence, the output will be displayed at the center.

Below is the code snippet

```
#!/bin/bash

INSTALLATION_HEADER=" Installater Options "

COLS=$(tput cols)

print_header ()
{
        local equal=()
        local title="$1"
        local mid=$(((${#title}+$COLS)/2))
        for (( i=0;  $i < ${#title} ; i=$(($i+1)) ))
        do
                local hypen+="-"
        done
        printf "%*s\n" $mid "$title"
        printf "%*s\n" $mid "$hypen"
        echo ""
        echo ""
}

print_install_options ()
{
        local title=${1}
        local mid=$(((${#title}+$COLS)/2))
        for (( i=0;  $i < ${#title} ; i=$(($i+1)) ))
        do
                local hypen+="-"
        done

        printf "%*s\n" $mid "$hypen"
        for i in "${install_options[@]}" ;
        do
                printf "%*s\n" $mid "$i"
        done
        printf "%*s\n" $mid "$hypen"
}

install_options=("1. Install" "2. Uninstall")
print_header "$INSTALLATION_HEADER"
print_install_options "$INSTALLATION_HEADER"
```

When I execute the above code, the output produced is

```
 Installater Options
---------------------


---------------------
           1. Install
         2. Uninstall
---------------------
```

The expected output should be

```
 Installater Options
---------------------


---------------------
1. Install
2. Uninstall
---------------------
```

"1. Ïnstall" and "2. Uninstall" are not printing at the middle of the screen. Please help me in resolving it.

Thanks in Advance.

## Updated Script:

Thanks to all for anwering my question.

Below is the script which gives the required output.

```
#!/bin/bash

INSTALLATION_HEADER=" Installater Options "

COLS=$(tput cols)

print_header ()
{
        local equal=()
        local title="$1"
        local mid=$(((${#title}+$COLS)/2))
        for (( i=0;  $i < ${#title} ; i=$(($i+1)) ))
        do
                local hypen+="-"
        done
        printf "%*s\n" $mid "$title"
        printf "%*s\n" $mid "$hypen"
        echo ""
        echo ""
}

print_install_options ()
{
        local title=${1}
        local length=$(((${#title}+$COLS)))
        local mid=$(((${#title}+$COLS)/2))
        for (( i=0;  $i < ${#title} ; i=$(($i+1)) ))
        do
                local hypen+="-"
        done

        printf "%*s\n" $mid "$hypen"
        for i in "${install_options[@]}" ;
        do
                printf "%*s%s" $((${mid}-${#title})) "" "|"
                printf "%s" "  $i  "
                printf "%*s\n" $((${#title}-${#i}-5)) "|"
        done
        printf "%*s\n" $mid "$hypen"
}

install_options=("1. Install" "2. Uninstall")
print_header "$INSTALLATION_HEADER"
print_install_options "$INSTALLATION_HEADER"
```

Output:

```
 Installater Options
---------------------


---------------------
|  1. Install       |
|  2. Uninstall     |
---------------------
```

Comment: Show expected output

Comment: @Jidder, Added the expected output. Thank you.

Comment: @sach I have added an answer where I address, in a note, the problem you might have referencing `$COLUMNS` inside a script.  Resumé: `$COLUMNS` works if you `source` the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change line 34 to

```
printf "%-*s%s\n" $((${mid}-${#title})) " " "$i"
```

Result:

```
                                 Installater Options 
                                ---------------------


                                ---------------------
                                1. Install
                                2. Uninstall
                                ---------------------
```

Comment: It works. Could you please explain the printf used here.

Comment: @sach `$((${mid}-${#title}))` is arithmetic operation which result is `$mid` minus length of `title`. So we printf two string (`%s`): first one is just bare space `" "` aligned to the left and repeated `mid` minus `#title` times. The second string is `$i`.

Comment: Thanks rooom, I have updated my script in the question, please have a look. Any changes plz suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
            printf "%*s\n" $mid "$i"
```

You need this:

```
            printf "%-*s\n" $mid "$i"
```

The `-` means left-align.

Comment: I am trying to print the statement which should start at the mid ( which is the center of the screen) value. Here left alignment does not work.

Comment: @sach the middle of the screen or the middle of the dashed lines ?

Comment: @Jidder, Its middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The question is about printing in the centre of a screen, even if the examples refer to a left aligned string (see John's answer for that...) so I will give the answer for centering a string even if it is of tangential interest for the OP

```
centre () {
    nc=`tput cols`; l=${#1}
    printf "%$(( (nc-l)/2 ))s%s\n" " " "$1"
    }
```

#### Comment for the OP

In your code you reference `$COLUMNS`, look at this:

```
% cat aaaa
echo pippo $COLUMNS
tput cols
% source aaaa
pippo 117
117
% sh aaaa
pippo
117
%
```

and use `tput` to find the number of columns